# Regex multiline to match string followed by text with arbitrary spaces in between

Tags: regex

Was wondering if any regex gurus can help figure out how to create a regular expression to solve this.  I am stumped.

I need to match "CUST-X" on variations of this multiline text..

```
"CUST-1 Some message\nLock-Id: Id74248cd199\n"
```

Requirement:

1. The "CUST-1" and "Some message" can be separated by a colon(:). The
   colon is optional.
2. There can be none, one or multiple spaces between
   the two strings.
3. Any number of spaces can be in front of "CUST-1".
4. There needs to be a message after "CUST-1". The message is
   arbitrary, there's no pattern to the message.
5. Ignore any other CUST-XX after the first one.  Only match on the 1st occurance.
6. java regex is preferable.

Examples:

Test strings that should match for "CUST-1"

```
"CUST-1 Some message\nLock-Id: Id14248cd199"
"  CUST-1 another message\nLock-Id: Id14258cd199"
"CUST-1:I like apples\nLock-Id: Id84248cd199"
"CUST-1: peaches are sweet\nLock-Id: Id78248cd199"
"CUST-1:    pies are great\nLock-Id: Id71248cd199"
```

Should match for "CUST-X" but not "CUST-X"

```
"CUST-1: Nice message about CUST-2\nLock-Id: Id74248cd199\n"
```

Test strings that should not match "CUST-1"

```
"CUST-1\nLock-Id: Id78248cd199"
"CUST-1  \nLock-Id: Id74248cd199"
"CUST-1:\nLock-Id: Id84248cd199"
"CUST-1:  \nLock-Id: Id94248cd199"
```

The closes I've come up with is..

```
^\\s*([A-Z]+-[0-9]+):?\\s+\\S+
```

But this will also match the cases where I do not want the match to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
^\\s*([A-Z]+-[0-9]+):?\\p{Z}+\\S+
```

`\s` matches any white space char defined as `[\t\n\f\r\p{Z}]`, which includes `\n`.

`\p{Z}` refers only to the whitespace char itself.

Comment: Thanks, that works great.  I only found one case where it didn't work for me, which I neglected to specify above.  "CUST-1 :  \nLock-Id: Id94248cd199"  matches but I don't want it to match (it has extra space after the 1).  Would be excellent if you could update your regex to handle that case as well but not a big deal.

Comment: Perhaps `^\\s*([A-Z]+-[0-9]+):?\\p{Z}+\\w+`, but it only works if _Some message_ always starts with a letter or a number.